# Ajax Post form Alert

Tags: javascript, json, ajaxform

If I post a Form and it goes to the next page(php,Sql) then another URL. How can I prevent a Ajax Result alert on the post page as the page has changed and moved on?  Should I just hide the result div or can I remove the function data?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //set var to bid number input field
    $("#favourites").click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
          
          //set var to bid number input field
        var content= $("#bidnumber").val();
        
        // Url to post to and Field name and content */          
        $.post('add_favourites.php', {bidnumber:content},
        
         // Alert Success
         function(data){
       
        // Alerts the results to this Div
            $("#favourites").html(data);
            
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand, but the code shown doesn't change the page. It just posts to a route then calls your function that injects the data into ```#favourites```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback `function(data) { ... }` is optional. You can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the content inside element `#favorites` after showing the success result.

```
     // Alert Success
     function(data){
        // Alerts the results to this Div
        $("#favourites").html(data);

        //Clear data
        setTimeout(function(){
             $("#favourites").html('');
        }, 5000);
     });
```